# Communicating between Google App Engine modules being slow

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I read an official app engine [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/microservices-on-app-engine) (which explains how to deploy micro services on app engine) and implemented a simple app. The problem is calling one module from another via `URLFetch` takes almost two seconds. I checked the log and found the 90% of the time was consumed by urlfetch. I used appspot.com domain as the doc suggested. I have no clue why it's so slow. Anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: As it is this question may prove difficult to answer. If the other module requires 2 seconds to respond this is fairly easy to explain. Another factor may be: Are you addressing the module via its own url or do you point your request to the general url which would add some overhead for module routing. Basically: When you provide a very simple reproduceable example of the problem (meaning code) it would be much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Let me repeat, 1. `appspot.com` domain was used, 2. URLFetch part took almost 2 seconds.

Comment: **a)** I can read and if you knew what i was asking for you would not childishly repeat what you've already said **b)** I was asking whether you're using a URL like `module-dot-app-id.appspot.com` or whether you request `app-id.appspot.com` and rely on the dispatch configuration **c)** urlfetch can take however long the request takes, you could try to fetch something small outside of appengine, preferable on a server with very high bandwidth, and see if that still takes 2 seconds. **d)** If you want SO users to consider helping you, you should rethink your strategy in regards to politeness.

Comment: I apologize. `module-dot-app-id.appspot.com` as used and no options were passed to urlfetch. Callee module returns almost json (no datastore call). The strange thing is that somethings it takes 2 seconds and sometimes takes 50ms.

Comment: It sounds like that could be a warm-up thing. To exclude this possibility you could switch your module to manual scaling with a single instance that's always running, and see what happens. Could also be a DNS thing - technically - i really hope Google doesn't have trouble resolving their very own DNS names.

Comment: Mmmm, the latency is completely random. I mean after even after warm-up, it's slow. I checked the tracer and the graphs shows that urlfetch part takes almost 2 seconds. Thought I also think the problem is because of DNS, the official doc suggest to use `module-app-id.appspot.com` instead of custom domain for the optimal routing. So I have no idea what to do.